# Flex 4 clicking on functions and vars from an source path class

Tags: eclipse, apache-flex, flex4

In my main project I have many libraries referenced by source path instead of referenced through the Library path. These are libs that I want to use in other projects too. Since I am allways changing them I use them as source path. I find it more practical and faster then moving to another project and looking for a class and then back to the main one ... and so on.

Problem is that when I click on a function or a member var to access the source class (ctr click), I get the error Resource '/bla/bla.as' does not exist. Isn't there a way to reference the sourcepath so when I "ctrl click" it opens the right class without showing this problem.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Right click > properties > build path > libraries > (Expand the library to which you want to set source) > source attachment > edit(In the right menu)

You will see something like this below. Attach it.

[image]